# qt5.15.3 Is it possible to Resize title bars Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button on QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

In Qt5.15.3
Enviromnent: Yocto Linux aarch64

I would like to resize the title bar buttons
such as Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button on QMainWindow

[image]

Is it possible ?

if yes is it possible to resize those button while the Mainwindow size changed
such as  adding size policy to Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button?

expecting:

1. resize the height and weight of  title bar buttons
   such as Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button on QMainWindow
2. If possible add sizepolicy to Expanding for the title bar buttons
   such as Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button on QMainWindow
   which make title bar buttons resize while the Mainwindow size changed

Comment: The native title bar is drawn by the window manager instead of the application. If you want to modify the title bar apperance, you need to create a frameless window and draw the title bar by the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
resize Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button in this function.

Comment: but the question is how am I going to modify  Close button,Maximize button, Minimize button provide by window manager ? Instead of redraw a new  title bar by the app itself

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).